# How to reference another value that meets certain conditions which can then be used in a calculation

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, match

I have to two data frames:

**Test**

```
Group.1   x
   1     25.5
   2     51
   3     51.5
   4     50
   5     51.5
   6     60 
   ...
   53    35.5
```

**Calendar**

```
Week   Hours  HourSpent
  1     8.5
  1     8.5
  1      0
  2     8.5
  2     8.5
  2     8.5
  2     8.5
  2     8.5
  2     6.5
  2     8.5
  3     7.0
  3     7.0
  3     8.2
  ...
```

What I am trying to do is to populate the 'HourSpent' column in the Calendar df by doing the following calculation: `(('Hours' / 'HourSpent') * 0.79)`

I want to be able to go through each line in the Calendar df and divide that rows 'Hours' value with the matching 'HourSpent' value. The 'HoursSpent' value can be decided from the 'Test' df...so if the value in the 'Week' column from the Calendar df matches any value in 'Group.1' column of the 'Test' df then I want the corresponding value in the 'x' column of the 'Test' df to be the 'HourSpent' value.

E.g.

Row 1 in the Calendar df will be `8.5 / 25.5 * 0.79`...which will apply to the top 3 rows as the week number is 1. Then when we get to row 4 the calculation would change to `8.5/ 51 * 0.79` and so on...etc

**Desired Output - Calendar df**

```
Week   Hours  HourSpent
  1     8.5     0.2633
  1     8.5     0.2633
  1      0        0
  2     8.5     0.1317
  2     8.5     0.1317
  2     8.5     0.1317
  2     8.5     0.1317
  2     8.5     0.1317
  2     6.5     0.1007
  2     8.5     0.1317
  3     7.0     0.1074
  ...
```

**Code Tried**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Calendar)){

 Calendar$'HourSpent' <- ifelse(Calendar$Week == Test$Group.1, 
 (Calendar$Hours/Test$x)*0.79, 
 0)

}
```

The problem is this only seems to work for one row then everything else is 0...is there a better solution to this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base `R` solution:

```
Test <- data.frame(Group.1 = 1:4, x = runif(4)*100, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Calendar <- data.frame(Week = sort(sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)), Hours = runif(10)*100, HourSpent = NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(Test)
# Group.1         x
# 1       1  7.163006
# 2       2 55.743758
# 3       3 48.983705
# 4       4 49.429236

head(Calendar)
# Week    Hours HourSpent
# 1    1 41.22831         NA
# 2    1 68.30103         NA
# 3    1 65.34278         NA
# 4    2 91.59863         NA
# 5    2 81.31131         NA
# 6    2 67.58900         NA

names(Test)[which(names(Test) == "Group.1")] <- "Week"

Calendar <- merge(Calendar, Test, by = "Week", all.x  = TRUE)

Calendar$HourSpent <- ((Calendar$Hours/Calendar$x) * 0.79)

head(Calendar)
# Week    Hours HourSpent         x
# 1    1 41.22831  4.5470251  7.163006
# 2    1 68.30103  7.5328452  7.163006
# 3    1 65.34278  7.2065835  7.163006
# 4    2 91.59863  1.2981349 55.743758
# 5    2 81.31131  1.1523431 55.743758
# 6    2 67.58900  0.9578707 55.743758
```

And I presume

> What I am trying to do is to populate the 'HourSpent' column in the Calendar df by doing the following calculation: (('Hours' / 'HourSpent') * 0.79)

has a typo in it? Because that'd require solving something of the form `Hours - HourSpent^2 = 0`.

**EDIT:**

Also, nothing wrong in using a `for loop` (especially if you are a beginner; but this can be slow on large data sets). So this is what your `for loop` would look like if we fleshed out its logic properly:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Calendar)){
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(Test)){
    
    if(Calendar$Week[i] == Test$Group.1[j] & is.na(Calendar$HourSpent[i])){
      
      Calendar$HourSpent[i] <- ((Calendar$Hours[i]/Test$x[j]) * 0.79)
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

(The basic idea: if the `Week` value and the `Group.1` value are equal/identical, and if the corresponding `HourSpent` column isn't filled in already, then calculate `HourSpent`.)

Comment: @Daisy see the edit to my post: it shows you how you can implement your `for loop` solution as well!!

Comment: Ah Brilliant! I will try the looped version now also...Thanks for that as I am still learning R myself, much appreciated :)

Comment: @Daisy you're welcome. You're doing a great job, I think. I wish you the best in your R journey!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Test <- data.frame(`Group.1` = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x = c(25.5, 51, 51.5, 50))
Calendar <- data.frame(Week = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Hours = c(8.5, 8.5, 0, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5))
Calendar <- dplyr::inner_join(Calendar, Test, by = c("Week" = "Group.1")) %>% 
            dplyr::mutate(Hours_spent = (Hours/x)*0.79)
```

**Output**

> Calendar

```
  Week Hours    x Hours_spent
1    1   8.5 25.5   0.2633333
2    1   8.5 25.5   0.2633333
3    1   0.0 25.5   0.0000000
4    2   8.5 51.0   0.1316667
5    2   8.5 51.0   0.1316667
6    2   8.5 51.0   0.1316667
7    3   8.5 51.5   0.1303883
8    3   8.5 51.5   0.1303883
9    3   8.5 51.5   0.1303883
```